# Use HUGE numbers in apple Swift

Tags: swift, numbers

I'm not a programmer, I just like to write some code in my free time! I used to program in python3, now I'm trying to learn apple's Swift. My problem:

in python3 I used without problems really huge numbers like 10**1000, I can print them, do math operations with them, and so on. In Swift, I can not do the same, because starting from 10**300 or 10**400, both Double and Float type gives "+infinity" as result, so I can not print it, nor do any operation with it...

How can I solve this? (PS. If anyone is interested, I'm trying to do some ProjectEuler's problems! http://projecteuler.net) Thank you in advance, and sorry for any mistake I could have maid, I'm not english, and it's my first time on StackOverflow!

Answer (score 7):

I'm working on a BigNumber library with which you can do some HUGE number calculations. Actually the library is based on the GNU Multiple Precision (GMP) library and I wrote an Objective-C / Swift wrapper. Currently big integer mathematics, including a lot of operator overloading, is possible. A code example goes like:

```
var err : NSError?
var bi1 = BigInt(nr: 12468642135797531)
var bi2 = BigInt(nr: "12345678901011121314151617181920", error: &err)
var res = bi1 * bi2
println("Multiply 2 BigInts: bi1 * bi2 = \(res.toString())")
```

which results in:

```
Multiply 2 BigInts: bi1 * bi2 = 153933852140173822960829726365674325601913839520
```

I hope the library (see: https://github.com/githotto/osxgmp) may be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is an official solution, weird no one ever mentioned(https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/test/Prototypes/BigInt.swift)
Delete the tests, then add `typealias BigInt = _BigInt<UInt>`, `BigInt` is ready to go

Comment: Must be approved answer

Answer (score 0):

If you know (or willing to learn) how to implement a bignumber, define your own type in swift (presumably  as a struct), then implement overloads of the arithmetic operators +, -, etc. and whatever else you need to work with those big numbers.

There's an implementation in C++ [here](https://code.google.com/p/bignumber-billjeff/), but if you google a little bit you might find other algorithms that you can translate into swift code, or examples in other languages (if you're not familiar with C++)

Swift already defines 2 "extended" floating point types named `Float80` and `Float96`:

```
Float80 80 bit MacOS float: 1 sign bit, 15 exponent bits, 1 integer bit, 63 fraction bits
Float96 96 bit 68881 float: 1 sign bit, 15 exponent bits, 16 pad bits, 1 integer bit, 63 fraction bits
```

but apparently no operator overload is defined - they are just "isolated" structs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! This is really strange, I did not even consider that It could be necessary to implement it by myself, I thought there was a built-in way to do this, just because a less complex language (as python can be) does it without problem. If I write 

`type(10**1000)` 

it gives me back **int** as result... Maybe this is not a beginner kind of problem to solve... :(

Comment: Don't forget that swift is still in beta, so it's still possible that it will have better support in version 1.0. In the meanwhile, if you like, you could file a radar.